# Visual Studio Code find in specific file type AND path

Tags: visual-studio-code, search

How do I global search in Visual Studio Code ( *Search: Find in Files* --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in *Windows* ) for just a specific file type (e.g. `*.js`) **AND** in a specific path (e.g. `./src/app`)?

I have tried using the following in the *files to include* field:

`./src/app, *.js`

but the comma separation query retrieves all the occurrences in **either** the path `./src/app` **or** the file type `*.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write a glob pattern:

```
./src/app/**/*.js
```

Any directory (`**`) and only the JavaScript (`*.js`) files